# Insert/show/load in json crashed

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout

First of all: 1. When i insert empty data into sql it crashed 2. When load json crashed 3. Pressing with empty data show records crashed Please help!

Here is MainActivity:

```
package com.example.user.notebook;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.user.notebook.Students;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout mainLayout=null;
    EditText lessons=null,student=null,grade=null,observations=null;
    Button insertRecord=null,showRecords=null;

    ArrayList<Students> result= new ArrayList<>();
    TableLayout resultLayout=null;
    Database db=null;

    LinearLayout jsonLayout=null;
    Button loadJSON=null,saveJSON=null;

    public void makeJSON()
    {
        jsonLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout.addView(jsonLayout);
        loadJSON=new Button(this);
        loadJSON.setText("LOAD JSON");
        jsonLayout.addView(loadJSON);
        loadJSON.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new
                        AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alert.setTitle("Load FILE");
                alert.setMessage("Specify file name: ");
                final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                alert.setView(input);
                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                            {
                                String value = input.getText().toString();
                                File myfile=new File(
                                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),value);
                                try {
                                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                            new InputStreamReader(new
                                                    FileInputStream(myfile), "utf8"),65536);
                                    String line="";
                                    line=br.readLine();
                                    try {
                                        JSONArray x=new JSONArray(line);
                                        Log.d("TEST","I have read "+x);
                                        int i;

                                        for(i=0;i<x.length();i++)
                                        {
                                            JSONObject p=x.getJSONObject(i);
                                            String lessons=p.getString("lessons");
                                            String student=p.getString("student");
                                            String observations=p.getString("observations");
                                            double grade =p.getDouble("grade");
                                            db.insert(lessons, student, observations, grade);
                                        }
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    br.close();

                                }catch(IOException e)
                                {
                                    Log.d("TEST",e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }});
                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                            {
                            }
                        });

                alert.show();
            }

        });
        saveJSON=new Button(this);
        saveJSON.setText("SAVE JSON");
        saveJSON.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                result=db.getResults();
                final JSONArray x=new JSONArray();
                int i;
                for(i=0;i<result.size();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject p=new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        p.put("lessons", result.get(i).lessons);
                        p.put("student",result.get(i).student);
                        p.put("observations", result.get(i).observations);
                        p.put("grade", result.get(i).grade);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    x.put(p);
                }
                String s=x.toString();
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new
                        AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alert.setTitle("Create FILE");
                alert.setMessage("Specify file name: ");
                final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                alert.setView(input);
                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                            {
                                String value = input.getText().toString();
                                File myfile=new File(
                                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),value);
                                try {
                                    Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                                            new FileOutputStream(myfile), "UTF8"));
                                    out.append(x.toString());
                                    out.flush();
                                    out.close();
                                    Log.d("TEST", "Write "+x);
                                }catch(IOException e)
                                {
                                    Log.d("TEST",e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }});
                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                            {
                            }
                        });

                alert.show();
            }


        });
        jsonLayout.addView(saveJSON);

    }

    public void makeInputs()
    {
        LinearLayout l1=new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout.addView(l1);
        lessons=new EditText(this);
        lessons.setHint("lessons");
        l1.addView(lessons);
        student=new EditText(this);
        student.setHint("student");
        l1.addView(student);
        observations=new EditText(this);
        observations.setHint("observations");
        l1.addView(observations);
        grade=new EditText(this);
        l1.addView(grade);
        grade.setHint("grade");
    }
    public void makeButtons()
    {
        LinearLayout l2=new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout.addView(l2);
        insertRecord=new Button(this);
        insertRecord.setText("INSERT RECORD");
        l2.addView(insertRecord);
        showRecords=new Button(this);
        showRecords.setText("SHOW RECORDS");
        l2.addView(showRecords);
        insertRecord.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                db.insert(lessons.getText().toString(),
                        student.getText().toString(),
                        observations.getText().toString(),
                        Double.parseDouble(grade.getText().toString()));
            }

        });
        showRecords.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                result=db.getResults();
                updateTable();

            }

        });
    }

    public void makeTable()
    {
        resultLayout=new TableLayout(this);
        ScrollView scroll=new ScrollView(this);
        mainLayout.addView(scroll);
        scroll.addView(resultLayout);
        TableRow r1=new TableRow(this);
        resultLayout.addView(r1);
    }

    public void updateTable()
    {
        resultLayout.removeAllViews();
        makeTable();
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<result.size();i++)
        {
            Students c=result.get(i);
            TableRow r=new TableRow(this);
            resultLayout.addView(r);
            TextView t1,t2,t3,t4;
            t1=new TextView(this);
            t1.setText(c.lessons);
            t2=new TextView(this);
            t2.setText(c.student);
            t3=new TextView(this);
            t3.setText(c.observations);
            t4=new TextView(this);
            t4.setText(""+c.grade);
            r.addView(t1);
            r.addView(t2);
            r.addView(t3);
            r.addView(t4);
            ImageView delimage=new ImageView(this);
            r.addView(delimage);
            delimage.setId(i);
            delimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.remove);
            delimage.setClickable(true);
            delimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String cardetails="lessons: "+
                            result.get(v.getId()).lessons+
                            " lessons: "+
                            result.get(v.getId()).student+
                            " student: "+
                            result.get(v.getId()).observations+
                            "observations: "+
                            result.get(v.getId()).grade+
                            " grade: ";
                    Log.d("TEST","Delete school is "+cardetails);

                }

            });
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mainLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
        setContentView(mainLayout);
        mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        db=new Database(this, "school.db", null, 2);
        makeInputs();
        makeButtons();
        makeJSON();
        makeTable();
    }
}
```

Database

```
package com.example.user.notebook;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private Context mcontext;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    public Database(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
                    int version) {
        super(context, name, null, version);
        mcontext=context;
        database=this.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table school(lessons text,student text,observations text,grade double)");
    }
    public ArrayList<Students> getResults()
    {
        ArrayList<Students> x= new ArrayList<Students>();
        Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery("select * from school",null);
        if(cursor.getCount()==0)
        {
            cursor.close();
            return x;
        }
        int lessonsindex=cursor.getColumnIndex("lessons");
        int studentindex=cursor.getColumnIndex("student");
        int observationsindex=cursor.getColumnIndex("observations");
        int gradeindex=cursor.getColumnIndex("grade");
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do
        {
            Students c;
            c=new Students(cursor.getString(lessonsindex),
                    cursor.getString(studentindex),
                    cursor.getString(observationsindex),
                    cursor.getDouble(gradeindex));
            x.add(c);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
        return null;

    }
    public void delete(String lessons,String student, String observations, double grade)
    {
        database.execSQL("delete from school where lessons='"+lessons+"' and student='"+
                student+"'and observations='"+observations+"' and grade = '"+grade);
    }
    public void insert(String lessons,String student, String observations, double grade)
    {
        database.execSQL("insert into school(lessons,student,observations,grade) values('"+
                lessons+"','"+student+"','"+observations+"','"+grade+"')");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table school");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void clearData()
    {
        database.execSQL("delete from school");
    }

}
```

LogCat:

> 01-24 22:10:49.962 2421-2421/? E/Zygote: v2
>   01-24 22:10:49.972 2421-2421/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
>   01-24 22:14:42.292 2421-2421/com.example.user.notebook E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: com.example.user.notebook, PID: 2421
>                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                at com.example.user.notebook.MainActivity.updateTable(MainActivity.java:257)
>                                                                                at com.example.user.notebook.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:235)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4808)
>                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19918)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5608)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1397)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1192)

also

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                         Process: com.example.user.notebook, PID: 4373
>                         java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
>                             at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
>                             at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
>                             at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
>                             at com.example.user.notebook.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:230)
>                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4808)
>                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19918)
>                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5608)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1397)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1192)

Comment: You need to post the stacktrace from the crash. Also, take your code out of block quotes and just use the code block so it will look better.

Comment: Everything is fixed and updated.

Comment: your .size() is null. pretty simple. you are trying to iterate through an empty array.....

Answer (score 1):

Youre trying to go through results.size() which is null. Follow your code.

```
.....
result=db.getResults();
                final JSONArray x=new JSONArray();
                int i;
                for(i=0;i<result.size();i++)
....
```

This will go into the db.getResults.

```
public ArrayList<Students> getResults()
    {
        ArrayList<Students> x= new ArrayList<Students>();
        Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery("select * from school",null);
        if(cursor.getCount()==0)
        {
            cursor.close();
            return x;
        }
        int lessonsindex=cursor.getColumnIndex("lessons");
        int studentindex=cursor.getColumnIndex("student");
        int observationsindex=cursor.getColumnIndex("observations");
        int gradeindex=cursor.getColumnIndex("grade");
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do
        {
            Students c;
            c=new Students(cursor.getString(lessonsindex),
                    cursor.getString(studentindex),
                    cursor.getString(observationsindex),
                    cursor.getDouble(gradeindex));
            x.add(c);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
        return null;

    }
```

If you look at this method...you are returning x, but x is null. You are not adding anything to X. Then... you return null at the end.... this is where your issue is.

PS: please use better names for your variables.

```
ArrayList<Students> x= new ArrayList<Students>();
```

could be a lot better and easier to understand if it was something like....

```
ArrayList<Students> studentsResults = new ArrayList<Students>();
```

Now obviously you don't have to do it, but it makes more easier to read code...and its cleaner...way cleaner

Comment: When delete a data, ex. lessons=namelala student=lalala grade=3.0 observations it crashed.

Comment: because your list is null.... do x.size() in getResults() and see if it shows up in log.

Comment: Sorry but i am beginner. You mean result=db.getResults();
                final JSONArray x=new JSONArray();
                int i;
                for(i=0;i<x.size();i++)
                {    ??? cause that it is not impossible

Comment: no. do a System.out.println(x.size()); within the getResults. Run the app and see what happens. put it before you return x and before you return null;

Comment: What about when i pressing empty insert saying java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

Comment: that could be that you are either returning a string and it should be a double. or youre return a double and you have int...or return a int and you expect a double. thats what NFE means. if you return a double... int you get something like int number = db.get("number"); and "number" is actually a double. for example

Comment: It is in the title and in the begin i refering to this. Its understanding what you say but in practice is confusing me.

Comment: look at your LOGCAT. -> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object

Comment: before you right anymore code... think about your logic. i think you are almost there.... but you are not adding anything to your list before you get the results.......

Comment: i see that, all make sense that is null

Comment: Tried do x.size() in getResults() in public ArrayList<Students> getResults() but still the same

Comment: "but you are not adding anything to your list before you get the results" can you make is clear by coding please?

Comment: I think that the `return null` at the end should be `return x`.

Comment: I did that but still the same

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues, the first masking the second which was more obvious and hence the initial attempts to fix that which resulted in nothing working.

- The first issue is that you were getting the **result** array in the `onCLick` and then calling the updateTable() method, in which the result array retrieved was not in the scope of the `updateTable` method. So moving `result=db.getResults();` onto the `updateTable` method, resolved that issue.
- The second issue was that the `getResults` would, if any rows were extracted, return null.

So to fix the issues and also condense the code, instead of (to fix issue 2):-

```
public ArrayList<Students> getResults()
    {
        ArrayList<Students> x= new ArrayList<Students>();
        Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery("select * from school",null);
        if(cursor.getCount()==0)
        {
            cursor.close();
            return x;
        }
        int lessonsindex=cursor.getColumnIndex("lessons");
        int studentindex=cursor.getColumnIndex("student");
        int observationsindex=cursor.getColumnIndex("observations");
        int gradeindex=cursor.getColumnIndex("grade");
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do
        {
            Students c;
            c=new Students(cursor.getString(lessonsindex),
                    cursor.getString(studentindex),
                    cursor.getString(observationsindex),
                    cursor.getDouble(gradeindex));
            x.add(c);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
```

It could instead be :-

```
public ArrayList<Students> getResults()
{
    ArrayList<Students> x= new ArrayList<Students>();
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery("select * from school",null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        x.add(new Students(
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lessons")),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("student")),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("observations")),
                cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("grade"))
        ));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return x;
}
```

Additionally, to fix (1) in the updateTable method add `result=db.getResults();` e.g.

```
public void updateTable()
{
    result=db.getResults(); //<<<< ADDED
    resultLayout.removeAllViews();
    makeTable();
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<result.size();i++)
    {
```

Remove the now unecessary `result=db.getResults();` from the `showRecords.setOnClickListener`'s `onClick` method.

This both condenses the code and also will not return a null but rather an ArrayList that is either populated or has a size of 0.

Thus circumventing the `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference`

Comment: it says getString
(int)
in Cursor cannot be applied
to
(int,
double)

Comment: Edit your question to include Students.java. Might save a bit of time trying to create it.

Comment: Whole project into java you mean?

Comment: Ok ignore last comment re adding student.java, I've corrected the `getResults` method, so use the one that is now in the answer (only slightly different, just a typo). Note also change `upDate` table method as per answer.

Comment: When i paste your answer gets that: getString (int) in Cursor cannot be applied to (int, double)

Comment: I changed the answer, you need to paste again.

Comment: Still the same as i said with applied to (int, double)

Comment: Ooop sorry, I think I forgot to save edit. try again.

Comment: Now it is okey, thank you but unfortunaly when delete a database says unrecognized token: "'7.0" (code 1): , while compiling: delete from school where lessons='a' and student='a'and observations='kmfcj' and grade = '7.0

Comment: That's a different issue, we've moved you on from the Null Pointer Exception. Please ask mark this question as answered and ask another question in that regard.

Comment: Okey, thak you very much for your return answer.

Comment: PS I'll be looking out for next question.

Comment: I am a begginer here so i do not know the rules. I will waiting cause there is a limit when i get to create a new question and i need so much answers...

Comment: The issue is that you have an extra single quote change the `delete` method to use :- `database.execSQL("delete from school where lessons='"+lessons+"' and student='"+
                student+"'and observations='"+observations+"' and grade = "+grade);`  i.e remove single quote after `grade =`

Comment: Instead of `....grade = '"+grade);` remove the **`'`** thus use `...grade = "+grade);` (easiest just copy and paste from the previous comment.)

Comment: there is no ' in ...grade = "+grade. its database.execSQL("delete from school where lessons='"+lessons+"' and student='"+student+
                "'and observations='"+observations+"' and grade= "+grade);

Comment: @RubenOchoaPerez this statement, "I do not know how but works"... you NEED to understand how code works in order to be able to recognize issues like this in the future. please take the time to run through the code in your head and ask questions if you still do not understand it. that was my downfall when i started. i grabbed code from stack without understanding what i was pasting. you HAVE to understand code or else youll never get to be where you want to be.

Comment: @DroiDev exacly, i`ll never understand programming, when i try hard it gets harder and harder. Maybe i am stupid.

Comment: @RubenOchoaPerez maybe.... haha. jk. you have to read the code as youre typing it. think about what you are trying to do. you had everything there, u just were ADDING a student. you add to ADD a student to the list in order to GET them. now, understanding that is one thing, knowing the syntax that goes with it is another. keep it up, youll get there

Comment: @MikeT  I am just posted my other question, you can check.